# when we redirecting the page it showing 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found in codeigniter using ngnix

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

when we redirecting the page it showing 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found on codeigniter using ngnix

[image: 404 Page Not Found]

Comment: This says your url is not available. Please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your controller name?? show me code of your `redirect` line.

Comment: If you are using `nginx`, you don't need `.htaccess` tag.

Answer (score 1):

First, connect your server via ssh and send this command:

```
nginx -t
```

It will test your nginx configuration file and show the config file's path. Than open your config file and add these under html {} section (before  `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` line):

```
server {
        server_name yourdomain.tld;

        root /your/codeigniters/full/path;
        index index.html index.php;

        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
}
```

If there is no `fastcgi.conf` in the same folder with `nginx.conf`, please create one and add these lines:

```
#fastcgi.conf
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

That's all!

Comment: Hi deniz,thanks for your response, where to create the document nginx.conf and fastcgi.conf and where should include the above code which u have given

Comment: You don't need to create nginx.conf file, it's already there. Just connect your server via ssh and type `nginx -t` and hit enter. You'll see the nginx.conf path.

Comment: Did you make what I said? If you made, please restart nginx and try again.

Comment: yes i restart it,again it showing the error error 404 Not Found nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)...

Comment: Can you make `nginx -t` and send me output?

Comment: pls check the below: root@Mobapp:/# nginx -t;
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: OK, open /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and send me all file.